# How can I install Brew on a Mac M2?

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I tried to install brew using the below command on my Mac M2.

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

then I type the password as prompted, and it keeps asking me to install the git command tools. However, after the git command tools were installed, I tried to run the above command line again and it kept asking me to install the git command line.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Nbf.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

It's not asking for the `git` command tools, it's asking for the Command Line Tools, which are part of XCode. Run this command to install the CLT without also installing XCode. XCode is a massive install, the CLT should be < 200 MB.

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

You'll get a prompt to allow the installation, just click "Install" and it should proceed.